# Laravel: WHERE(...) AND ( cond1 OR cond2 ...) always creates AND condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've used passing a query object to a sub-function many times, with no issues. However, when I want an OR relationship, the query builder is very OCD and always gives me AND!

**Business Logic**: `site_id = $site_id AND (cond1 OR cond2 OR ..)`  *cond1..n* is taken from `$cols` any are matched `$search`.

```
$cols = "priority, status, name, actionType"
```

`$search` is the string to be searched for, in this case: *Medium*

The issue here is **not the missing column**, that's there to create the error to spit out the SQL. The issue how to get Laravel to behave properly with orWhere and parenthesis.

First method:

```
$data = $this->where('site_id', $site_id) ;
$data = $this->search($cols, $orderBy, $search, $data) ;
```

Second method **(search(...)**):

```
    $searches = explode(',', $col);

    $len = sizeof($searches) ;

    if ($len > 0) {
      for ($i=0; $i < $len ; $i++) {
        $val = trim($searches[$i]) ;

        $data->where(function ($query) use ($val, $search, $data) {
          $query->orWhere(function ($query1) use ($val, $search, $data) {
          $query1->orWhereRaw("$val LIKE '%$search%'");
        }) ;
      }) ;
    }  // for
   }  // if
```

I've deliberately left an unknown column to see the SQL Laravel generates:

```
Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `actions` where `site_id` = 555 and ((priority LIKE '%Medium%')) and ((status LIKE '%Medium%')) and ((name LIKE '%Medium%')) and ((actionType LIKE '%Medium%')))
```

As you can see, despite multiple orWhere's I still get ANDs! Because the second method is in the base model, it's designed for all queries, I trying to avoid excessive duplicated searching functions.

The SQL is nearly what I want.

If I omit the  following code:

```
//        $data->where(function ($query) use ($val, $search, $data) {
          $data->orWhere(function ($query1) use ($val, $search, $data) {
          $query1->orWhereRaw("$val LIKE '%$search%'");
        }) ;
//      }) ;
```

With the result of:

```
Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `actions` where `site_id` = 555 or (priority LIKE '%Medium%') or (status LIKE '%Medium%') or (name LIKE '%Medium%') or (actionType LIKE '%Medium%')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit query in your code

```
$data = $this->where('site_id', $site_id) ; // where `site_id` = 555

$searches = explode(',', $col);

$len = sizeof($searches) ;

if ($len > 0) {
        $data->where(function ($query) use ($search, $len, $searches) // AND
        {
            for ($i=0; $i < $len ; $i++) {
                $val = trim($searches[$i]) ;

                $query->orWhereRaw("$val LIKE '%$search%'"); //  (priority LIKE '%Medium%' or status LIKE '%Medium%' or name LIKE '%Medium%' or actionType LIKE '%Medium%')
            }
        });
    }

    dd($data->toSql());
```

Comment: Thanks Ruchi, but I'm getting this SQL back from that query:
select count(*) as aggregate from `actions` where `site_id` = 555 and `priority, status, actionType, summary` LIKE %%)

Answer (score 1):

Having two `where()` calls will always create an `AND`.
Having one `where()` and one `orWhere()` will resulting in an `OR`.

So either do this:

```
$data = $this->search($cols, $orderBy, $search, $data) ;
$data = $this->orWhere('site_id', $site_id) ;
```

Or this:

```
    $searches = explode(',', $col);

    $len = sizeof($searches) ;

    if ($len > 0) {
      for ($i=0; $i < $len ; $i++) {
        $val = trim($searches[$i]) ;

        $data->orWhere(function ($query) use ($val, $search, $data) {
          $query->orWhere(function ($query1) use ($val, $search, $data) {
          $query1->orWhereRaw("$val LIKE '%$search%'");
        }) ;
      }) ;
```

Edit: after re-reading your question and your comment I think you're looking for an additional `where()` wrapping the for-looped `orWhere()` calls. Something like this:

```
    $searches = explode(',', $col);

    $len = sizeof($searches) ;

    if ($len > 0) {

      $data->where(function ($query) use ($val, $search, $data) {
        for ($i=0; $i < $len ; $i++) {
          $val = trim($searches[$i]) ;

          $data->orWhere(function ($query) use ($val, $search, $data) {
            $query->orWhere(function ($query1) use ($val, $search, $data) {
            $query1->orWhereRaw("$val LIKE '%$search%'");
          }) ;
        }) ;
      }) ;
```

Comment: Thanks @PtrTon, I'm still getting a OR between site_id=XXX and the sub-conditions. It should be `site_id=XXX and (cond1 OR cond2 ...)`. I'm still getting this:
```select count(*) as aggregate from `actions` where `site_id` = 555 or ((priority LIKE '%Medium%')) or ((status LIKE '%Medium%')) or ((name LIKE '%Medium%')) or ((actionType LIKE '%Medium%'))```

The reason I want the first condition evaluated `site_id=XXX`, is for performance reasons, since that will reduce the data set for the second condition to evaluate.

Comment: I think I understand the issue you're having now and I've updated my answer. Could you have another look?

Comment: Just implemented that- great minds think alike! However, no banana:
```
select count(*) as aggregate from `actions` where `site_id` = 555 and `priority, status, actionType, summary` LIKE %%)
```